# Rails 4.2 - Is the last record's #created_at more than 1 day old?

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, time, comparison

I have a couple of classes that require a record/object created daily to be considered 'up-to-date' within my application.

Here are the methods I use to determine how recent the latest record was created.

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .
  def medical_record_expired?
    if self.medical_record_forms.last.created_at::time <= 1.day.ago
      true
    else
      false
    end
    # ((Time.current - self.medical_record_forms.last.created_at)/3600).to_i
  end

  def personal_care_log_expired?
    if self.personal_care_forms.last.created_at::time <= 1.day.ago
      true
    else
      false
    end
    # ((Time.current - self.personal_care_forms.last.created_at)/3600).to_i
  end
end
```

My latest MedicalRecord's date is 12/17/2017
[image: MedicalRecord visual]

My latest PersonalCare's date is 12/21/2017
[image]

This is something that I built a while ago and I used to think that something simple such as `object.created_at <= 1.day_ago` would return true for any date  less than 1 day old.

I'm using postgresql 21 and below is my time zone config:

[image]

I can get the methods to work when running their internals in a console, so I figured this may be a time-zone conversion issue.

But I've tried out quite a few approaches that help with time-zone and other scenarios such as beginning_of_day, ::time and :to_i to calculate the n of hours that have passed, if less than 24 than the record is 'up-to-date', over 24hrs than it isn't.

I will also include my views in case I have something backwards there.

medical_record snippet:

```
<% if resident.medical_record_expired? %>
  <td class="text-center move-row">
    <label class="label label-danger">
      Record outdated, 
      <%= link_to "<span class='pad-all text text-lg text-primary'>click here</span>".html_safe, new_resident_medical_record_form_path(resident.id) %>
      to create.
    </label>
  </td>
<% else %>
  <td class="text-center move-row">
    <label class="label label-table label-success">Up to date!</label>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

personal_care_logs snippet:

```
<% if resident.personal_care_log_expired? %>
  <td class="text-center move-row">
    <label class="label label-danger">
      Record outdated, 
      <%= link_to "<span class='pad-all text text-lg text-primary'>click here</span>".html_safe, new_resident_personal_care_form_path(resident.id) %>
      to create.
    </label>
  </td>
<% else %>
  <td class="text-center move-row">
    <label class="label label-table label-success">Up to date!</label>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

I'm interested in learning what I have overlooked/misapplied that prevents me from reaching this end.

**12/26/17 Update**

Following the steps outlined below, I was able to determine that this problem exists for only one Resident and his nested-association, `resident.personal_care_forms.last`. The last created_at was printing as being days ago *(12/21)*, even though the latest record was created today *(12/26)*.

When attempting to add new `personal_care_forms` for other residents, the conditional pulls the record with the most recent `created_at` date as expected.

I am unsure why the original `resident.personal_care_forms.last` still does not pick up that I created a new record today as well. I can rebuild the db as this isn't a problem with production data.

Many thanks for the debug tip as it helped me reason through with greater ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `self.personal_care_forms.last.created_at < 1.day.ago` should work and behave the same in the console and in the app.

Try adding logs to your Resident class like this (note that I also collapsed boolean returns) and see what you're getting:

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .
  def medical_record_expired?
    puts "created_at: #{medical_record_forms.last.created_at} 1.day.ago: #{1.day.ago}"
    self.medical_record_forms.last.created_at < 1.day.ago
  end

  def personal_care_log_expired?
    puts "created_at: #{personal_care_forms.last.created_at} 1.day.ago: #{1.day.ago}"
    self.personal_care_forms.last.created_at < 1.day.ago
  end
end
```